# Show that $\lim_{r \rightarrow 1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^{2^n}= \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I was doing an exercise of complex analysis (from Stein's book), and in order to show a function could not be analytically continuated beyonde the unit circle, I needed that $\displaystyle \lim_{r \rightarrow 1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^{2^n}= \infty$. However, I do not know how to prove it. I believe an explicit formula for that series is beyond grasp, and I have no idea how to proceed. ($r$ is a real number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $0 < r < 1$, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{2^n} > \sum_{n=1}^k r^{2^n} > k\cdot r^{2^k}$$

for all $k \geqslant 1$. If $r^{2^k} \geqslant \frac12$, the right hand side is $\geqslant \frac{k}{2}$.

Comment: But the condition $r^{2^k}\geq\frac12$ forces $k$ to be small, so we can't say that the sum is larger than something that gets arbitrarily large.

Comment: ... but using your inequality, for each $k\geq 1$,  $$\lim_{r\to 1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{2^n}\geq \lim_{r\to 1} kr^{2^k} = k,$$ so the result holds.

Comment: We choose $k$ first, and then make $r$ large enough so that $r^{2^k} \geqslant \frac{1}{2}$, i.e. $r \geqslant \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1/2^k}$. That way, for any given constant $C$, we find an $r_C < 1$ such that the sum is $> C$ for all $r \geqslant r_C$.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the summands tend to 1, if r tends to 1, the sum clearly diverges

Answer (score 0):

Use

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{(n^2)}>\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{2n}=\frac{1}{1-r^2}-1=\frac{1}{1-r}\left(\frac{r^2}{1+r}\right).$