# Does $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n!} = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Does $\lim_{r \to 1^-} \sum_{n=0}^\infty r^{n!} = \infty$?

I am working on a complex analysis question that asks to show $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n!}$ cannot be extended past the open unit disk.  My method of proof was to show $\lim_{r \to 1^-} \sum_{n=0}^\infty r^{n!}e^{2 \pi i p/q}$ blows up.  Since for $n \geq q$ this series is equal to $\sum r^{n!}$, the question is reduced to that above.

I feel like this should be obvious, but for whatever reason I'm not comfortable with the intuitive "proof" by contradiction that if the limit were finite, then the series would converge at $r=1$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For a solution, I piggybacked off of this answer:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691094/show-that-lim-r-rightarrow-1-sum-n-1-infty-r2n-infty?rq=1

Comment: The fact that $$\lim_{r\to1^-} \sum_{n=0}^\infty r^{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lim_{r\to1^-} r^{n!}$$ follows from the fact that all the summands are nonnegative (Tonelli's theorem).

Comment: Don't you mean by the Monotone Convergence Theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $N\in \mathbb N,$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N}x^{n!}<\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n!}$$ for $x\in (0,1].$ Thus

$$\liminf_{x\to 1^-} \sum_{n=0}^{N}x^{n!} = \lim_{x\to 1^-} \sum_{n=0}^{N}x^{n!} =N \le \liminf_{x\to 1^-}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n!}$$

Since $N$ is arbitrary, the $\liminf$ on the right is $\infty,$ which is the desired result.